# Loading image from client computer and determining its dominant hue

Tags: javascript, image, colors, filesystems

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way I can load an image from a visitor's computer using a file input and make it accessible from JavaScript to perform operations on it? (must be compatible with at least IE 7)
2. Do browsers provide functions to analyse pictures like the PHP library GD does or are there libraries that can do it? (getColorAt(x, y), etc)

I need to determine the dominant hue of a wallpaper before I put it in my gallery. Most free web hosting services only allow 16 Megabytes of RAM per user, so this has to be done on client side.

Comment: By dominant hue do you mean simply the hue that appears most often in an image ? It is interesting how a answer was accepted without even mentioning how one would do that. You might as well change the title and question's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is there a way I can load an image from a visitor's computer using a file input and make it accessible from JavaScript to perform operations on it ? (must be compatible with at least IE 7)

You would need to use either the [File API](http://caniuse.com/#search=file%20api), which isn't supported by IE7, or a plug-in (e.g. a Java applet).

> 2) Do browsers provide functions to analyse pictures like the PHP library GD does or are there libraries that can do it ? (getColorAt(x, y), etc)

It is possible to get colour data via [canvas](http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas), but again, no support for old-IE.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I've looked for image processing libraries and as you say canvas support is necessary.
Would you recommend me to use a flie API or a Java Applet ?

Comment: Given the requirement for IE 7 support, File API and canvas are not options. A Java Applet is a possible option, but not a nice one. I'd recommend buying hosting that isn't free and nasty and then doing it server side.

Comment: Well it's not really a requirement. That's a personnal web site i'm working on so i don't have profitability constraints.
This is a wallpaper sharing website so the main targeted audience will be geeks like me who are unlikely to use ie7.
Let's say i raise the limit to ie9 so i can use the canvas, that file API seems really bad supported for now, so i suppose i should try an applet.